# Solution to a laplace equation on the unit sphere.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, spherical-coordinates, laplacian

I'm looking for $H(\theta,\varphi)$ ( $ 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq \varphi < 2 \pi$) a solution of the following equation

$$\Delta_{S} H(\theta,\varphi) = \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \varphi := f(\theta,\varphi)$$

where $\Delta_{S}$ is the laplacian on the unit sphere defined by

$$\Delta_{S}  H(\theta,\varphi) := \frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial^2 \theta} (\theta,\varphi) + \frac{1}{\tan \theta } \frac{\partial H}{\partial \theta}  (\theta,\varphi) + \frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta} \frac{\partial H}{\partial \varphi^2}  (\theta,\varphi).$$

I'm looking for a method to find solutions to equation on this type, I'm also interested on other kind of source term $f(\theta,\varphi)$ but always with the form of a trigonometric polynomial in $(\theta,\varphi)$.

I was thinking of writing $H(\theta,\varphi):= \cos^m(\theta) \sin^{n}(\theta) \cos^p(\varphi) \sin^q(\varphi)$ and try to find the good exponent $(n,m,p,q)$.

**Edit**

A decomposition in spherical harmonics $H(\theta,\varphi):= \sum_{l=0}^{+ \infty} \sum_{m=-l}^l C_{l,m} Y_{l,m}(\theta,\varphi)$ seems more appropriate to use as they form an hilbert basis made of eigenvalues of $\Delta_S$, as

$$- \Delta_S Y_{l,m} = l(l+1) Y_{m,l}.$$

However there is one issue. Writing the source term

$$f(\theta, \varphi) = \sin^2 \theta  \cos^2 \varphi = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{2} + \frac{\sin^2 \theta \ \cos 2 \varphi}{2}$$

we see that the first spherical harmonic $Y_{00}(\theta,\varphi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi}}$ will appear in this decomposition. This harmonic belongs to the kernel of the operator $\Delta_{S}$ and thus it will not be possible to inverse the system

$$\Delta_S \Big(\sum_{l=0}^{+ \infty} \sum_{m=-l}^l C_{l,m} Y_{l,m}(\theta,\varphi) \Big) = f(\theta,\varphi).$$

Any suggestion or references on this kind of equation is welcomed.

Comment: That is exactly what you should do. Note that you also have a homogeneous solution that can be found by separation of variables i.e the full solution is given by $H = H_{h} + H_{p}$ with $H_{h} = T(\theta) V(\varphi)$ that satisfies $$\Delta_{S} H_{h} = 0$$ and $H_{p} = \cos^{m} \theta \sin^{n} \theta \cos^{p} \varphi \sin^{q} \varphi$ solves $$\Delta_{S} H_{p} = f(\theta, \varphi)$$

Comment: @mattos I was thinking also of using the spherical harmonics which seems like a better choice to express the solution

Comment: Whatever coordinates or formalism you choose, the rotation-invariant Laplacian on spheres annihilates constants, so, indeed, the Laplacian is not invertible. But adding suitable constants does make it invertible...